# file.encoding system property in Java giving different results in different instances of JVM

Tags: java, tomcat, utf-8, jvm, java-7

I am running Java 7 on Centos 6.6. I checked `file.encoding` system property in an instance of standalone tomcat server it showed `UTF-8`. I check the same in an embedded tomcat it showed `ANSI_X3.4-1968`. Both instances are not taking any command line arguments for `file.encoding`.

The mystery is why does JVM infer `ANSI_X3.4-1968` in embedded tomcat only? In all other instances it correctly infers `UTF-8` based on my locale settings.

Comment: `file.encoding` can be set in the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` environment variable. I would log that in both cases and see if it differs.

Comment: Both processes are running on the same system/JVM/etc.? Note that this has nothing to do with Tomcat.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Both processes are running on the same system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java (not Tomcat) sets `file.encoding` automatically if it's not given on the command line. It will use environment variables, like `locale` to work out an appropriate setting.

For example, my locale is `en_GB.UTF-8`, so my file.encoding is resolved to `UTF-8`.

The "embedded" instance may not have been given a full environment context, so has been unable to arrive at the same setting as the standalone instances.

Some more information about the embedded instance may help up shed more light.

Answer (score 1):

If you always want `file.encoding` to be set to `UTF-8`, then you must launch your JVM with this option:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Any reliance on the specific environment that is launching the JVM is not going to be reliable.